# Django Best Practice for Handling Related Model Objects Between Apps

Tags: python, django

I have a project that has 2 different apps.  One handles a site's performance metrics and the other estimates site's workload.  The workload app has some dependencies on the performance app.  However, I am trying to avoid creating a dependency from the metrics app to the workload app in order to better encapsulate the metrics app as stand-alone.  For example, metrics has this model:

```
# models.py in metrics app:
class Site(models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    site_geography = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='site_name', unique=True, null=True)
```

Workload app has objects such as (some omitted for brevity):

```
# models.py in workload app:
class Resource (models.Model):
    name_first = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    name_last = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    address_street = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    address_state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(metrics_models.Site, through='ResourceSiteRelationship', blank=True, related_name='resources')

class Activity (models.Model):
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    travel = models.BooleanField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class ResourceSiteRelationship (models.Model):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, related_name='resource_site_relationships')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='resource_site_relationships')
    site = models.ForeignKey(metrics_models.Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='resource_site_relationships')
```

Site should also have the following field relationship:

```
activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity, related_name='sites', blank=True)
```

Is it best to add that field to the metric's app's instance of Site?  Is it better to create a one-to-one class for Site in the workload app and extend like so:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    site = models.OneToOneField(metrics_models.Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity, related_name='sites', blank=True)
```

Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just putting a `ManyToManyField` to `Site` in `Activity` the way you did in `Resource`?

Comment: I was trying to follow the convention from Django Unleashed about putting the ManyToMany field in the object that would "own" the other objects...but your right!  I think that would fix my encapsulation problem nicely.  Thanks!